# Round answer based on what the user inputs?

Tags: java, rounding

I'm a new programmer, and I'm coding a basic decimal calculator. (in Java)

If the user inputs how many decimals they want to round to, say 2, how would I incorporate that into the code, and have the answer round to 2 decimals?

Right now, I have something like this:

```
System.out.printf("%.3f %n", ans);
```

But that will always round to 3 decimals, no matter what the user input is.
Here's a [link to the whole code](https://mega.nz/file/FIoh0SxT#sYMd3Iz6t1Jcl5XT2-xBkqO96upBgX7XK9FmHwF3L1Q), if necessary.
Is there a basic way to this?

Comment: Good question. Thanks for the nice writeup. I've linked to a couple of questions that have the answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow and welcome to programming, cheers!